# How to retain values of randomly generated HTML text fields on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating HTML text at runtime like my following code.

```
<?php
session_start();
for(var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{ 
?>
    <div id="mainDiv<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <input type="text" id="myText<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <button type="button" id="myButton<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="myButtonClicked()">Click Me</button>       
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

It is working fine. Problem is now in retaining the values of these textboxes. When I refresh the page, all the values previously entered are gone. Do I need to create 10 sessions to retain the values of these 10 texts? Or, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: So what happens here is when you refresh the page, the values are reset to their default.
You want to store the values when the user enter some text in the textfields so the values are shown the next time when the user refreshes the page. What you need to do is to either send ajax requests with the values to the server everytime the user enters a value, or store the values in cookies which you can retrieve later after the page is refreshed.

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon - Cookies would be the better option but do I need to create them in loop?

Comment: No because the textfields will have no values initially, you need to create them when the user enters some text in the textfield; probably everytime they enter a character

Comment: Other option could be `localStorage`.

Comment: @SumanBogati - Can you elaborate on this more with some code snippet?

Comment: Do one clear to me, Do you want to save all the values from input box by enter/type by user?

Comment: BTW, your text fields are not randomly generated, as the title suggests. They are generated dynamically.

Comment: @GOTO0 - ohh!! sorry, yes these are dynamically generated.

Comment: @SumanBogati - Yes, I want to save all the values which are entered by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `locaStorage` api for retain the user input by store/get to/from localStorage after page refresh.
`setItem()` and `getItem()` are used for store and get item from localStorage respectively.

**Example**

This **html** will be created by php

```
<input type="text" id="text1" value="" />
<button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="myButtonClicked('text1')">Click Me</button>

<input type="text" id="text2" value="" />
<button type="button" id="myButton1" onclick="myButtonClicked('text2')">Click Me</button>       
//like this other input and button will be created.
```

**JS**

```
if(localStorage.getItem('resArr') == null){
    var resultArr = [];
}else{
    resultArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('resArr'));
    //---- get stored item from localStorage by json parsing
}

alert('the last item you entered is ' + resultArr[resultArr.length-1]);
function myButtonClicked(id){
    var userVal = document.getElementById(id).value;
    resultArr.push(userVal);
    localStorage.setItem('resArr', JSON.stringify(resultArr));
    //stored the entered value in localStorage by doing stringify
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4w5L/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you exactly
but you can achieve what you want through a form that submits to php_self..

```
<?php

//create blank array for storing text box values
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
   $textValue[$i]='';}

//if page reached via submission of button, store posted text box values in array
if(isset($_POST['myButton'])){
   for($i=1;$i<=count($textValue);$i++){
      $textValue[$i]=$_POST['myText'.$i];}}

?>

 <!--create form that submits to same page-->
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="main">

<?php

//loop creates text boxes and buttons while getting text box default values from $textValue Array
for ($i=1;$i<=count($textValue);$i++){ 
   echo '<div id="mainDiv'.$i.'">
   <input type="text" id="myText'.$i.'" name="myText'.$i.'" value="'.$textValue[$i].'"/>
   <button id="myButton'.$i.'" name="myButton" value="myButton'.$i.'">Click Me</button>    
</div>
';}

?>

</form>
```